# Despite a Content-Length no estimated download time is displayed

Tags: google-chrome, http, http-headers

I am encountering something strange, when I download a file from my server there is no ETA for the download despite that the response header indicates the content length.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this was caused by the transfer encoding that is set to chunked.

> Whenever the trailers are used, the server should list their names in
>   the Trailer header field; 3 header field types are specifically
>   prohibited from appearing as a trailer field: Transfer-Encoding,
>   Content-Length and Trailer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding